Is it (or at least was it) colder on Tiangong than on the ISS? If so, why?
This answer to What's this dark, ceiling-mounted hemisphere in Tianhe module of Tiangong space station? Any counterpart on the ISS and if so what does it look like? links to the June 23, 2021 CGTN video A day in the life of taikonauts at the CSS
It shows the crew waking up and then wearing several layers of clothing - what looks like at least one extra layer compared to what I often see ISS crew wearing.
Now this is over three years old, and the station is probably bigger and more completely equipped, so maybe this was just a transition phase. Either way, I'd like to ask:
Question: Is it (or at least was it) colder on the Tiangong than on the ISS? If so, why?
Trigger alert (for me at least) the soundtrack begins with a loud, abrupt alarm clock!




Accessing docs that contain more info (or as much as there is on the ISS) beyond the usual media-friendly dribble takes a little longer to source. IIRC it was said to be 26 degrees, and the common description used is "Spring all year round". The astronauts are now quoted as wearing 'light clothing'; its probable that the thicker clothing is indeed from an earlier stage when the central heating probably wasn't in full flow yet.

@blobbymcblobby ya that's what I was wondering - thus the "Is it (or at least was it)..."

According to an Article, the Tiangong station was kept at 18°C - 26°C.
While the ISS also sits at a similar temperature of 18°C - 24°C according to a YouTube video.
Apparently these temperatures can be changed and made warmer according to an agreement between the crew and the commander.
So to answer your question, no it was most probably not colder. Either the commander refused to have higher temperatures, or the crew wore outer wearing as a formality.

I have a hunch that the standard outerwear was... standard. While westerners gravitate towards that individualized, casual look, even in space, in the east it's much more common in official situations and even not, to wear some kind of uniformized attire when working as a team or a group, or representing some organization.

ohhh, yeah makes sense.

the numbers in your answer seem to come from this paragraph "The thermal-control coating was first used on the Shenzhou-13 spaceship, which was launched on Oct 16, 2021. It kept the cabin environment within acceptable temperature ranges (between 18 and 26 degrees Celsius), allowing the taikonauts to stay comfortable in their orbiting home." which isn't about Tiangong.
